# How to join a result extracted from Database of each element of my array and return it in json in Laravel 8

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, laravel, eloquent

i am working on a Laravel 8 project and i have a bunch of categories that i selected in my multi select bar of my Form, and i want to return the suppliers in my database for each category i have selected so that i can display them in the next select bar of my Form,im using ajax for that but i don' seem to figure out how to combine the suppliers of each category in one final result so i get to send it back to my view in json , can someone tell me what am i doing wrong and how to fix this please ? here is my controller

```
public function get_fournisseurs(Request $request){
    try {
      if($request->ajax()) {
            $query = $request->get('selectednumbers');

            if(empty($query)) {
                return back()->withError("Désolé, une erreur de serveur s'est produite (requête vide)");
             }
            else {
                $fournisseurs[] = new FourCats();
                foreach ($query as $value) {
                    $fou[]=FourCats::join('fournisseurs','four_cat.four', '=', 'fournisseurs.id')
                        ->where('four_cat.cat','=', $value)
                        ->select('fournisseurs.id','fournisseurs.nomSociete','fournisseurs.id','fournisseurs.tel')
                        ->get();
                        foreach($fou as $f) {
                            $fournisseurs = implode(array($f));
                        }
                    $fournisseurs = implode(array( $fournisseurs));
                }
               return json_encode(array('data'=>$fournisseurs));

            }
        }

    } catch (\Throwable $th) {
        throw $th;
    }
```

and here is my ajax method

```
    $('#first-choice').change(function(){

        if( $('#first-choice :selected').length > 0){
            var selectednumbers = [];
            $('#first-choice :selected').each(function(i, selected) {
                selectednumbers[i] = $(selected).val();
            });
            console.log(selectednumbers);
            $.ajax({
                url: '{{ url('get_fournisseurs') }}',
                method:'GET',
                data: {selectednumbers: selectednumbers },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(dataResult){

                    var resultData = dataResult.data;
                    console.log(resultData);
                    $('#second-choice').empty();
                    $.each(JSON.parse(resultData), function(i,row){

                        $('#second-choice').append(new Option( row.id+'-'+row.nomSociete, row.id));
                    })
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

now this one works without errors except that the logic of my controller is wrong this code is showing me the suppliers of the last selected category even when i send 3 categories or more, i want the final result to combine the suppliers of all the selected categories not just the last one in the list, even with the double loop it isn't working please help me fix my loop logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what worked for me ^^ thank you for those who tried to help

My controller :

```
 public function get_fournisseurs(Request $request){
    try {
      if($request->ajax()) {
            $query = $request->get('selectednumbers');

            if(empty($query)) {
                return back()->withError("Désolé, une erreur de serveur s'est produite (requête vide)");
             }
            else {
                $fournisseurs=FourCats::join('fournisseurs','four_cat.four', '=', 'fournisseurs.id')
                    ->whereIn('four_cat.cat',$query)
                    ->select('fournisseurs.id','fournisseurs.nomSociete','fournisseurs.id','fournisseurs.tel')
                    ->distinct()
                    ->get();

              return json_encode(array('data'=>$fournisseurs));
               // return response()->json($fournisseurs);

            }
        }

    } catch (\Throwable $th) {
        throw $th;
    }
}
```

ajax methode :

```
$('#first-choice').change(function(){

        if( $('#first-choice :selected').length > 0){
            var selectednumbers = [];
            $('#first-choice :selected').each(function(i, selected) {
                selectednumbers[i] = $(selected).val();
            });
            console.log(selectednumbers);
            $.ajax({
                url: '{{ url('get_fournisseurs') }}',
                method:'GET',
                data: {selectednumbers: selectednumbers },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(dataResult){

                    var resultData = dataResult.data;
                    $('#second-choice').empty();
                    $.each(resultData, function(i,row){
                        $('#second-choice').append(new Option( row.id+'-'+row.nomSociete, row.id));
                    })
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Just delete or uncomment this line then it should work.
implode() makes a string but you need an array.
This is the reason that you get an conversion error.

```php
$fournisseurs = implode($fournisseurs);
```

And you define $fournisseurs=[]; twice. Just uncomment this.

Then do

```php
return response()->json($fournisseurs);
```

you can also check the json response with

```php
$data = response()->json($fournisseurs);
print_r($data)
```

I'm not an Laravel expert but I think you don't need that foreach loop everything from the database will be in the variable see:

```php
$fournisseurs = DB::table('yourTableName') -
  > join('fournisseurs', 'four_cat.four', '=', 'fournisseurs.id') -
  > select('fournisseurs.id', 'fournisseurs.nomSociete', 'fournisseurs.id', 'fournisseurs.tel') -
  > where('four_cat.cat', '=', $value) -
  > get();
  
return json_encode(array($fournisseurs));
```

Comment: i just edited my code and it doenst give me any errors now,But i have a logic problem how do i combine the result of each query of each category in my final $fournisseurs list?

Comment: I attached code above. Maybe that help you. I think you don't need that for each. Your full response will be in the variable $fournisseurs

Comment: this is the result

Comment: data: "[{\"id\":1,\"nomSociete\":\"A G M I\",\"tel\":\"05.61.96.82.12\"},{\"id\":2,\"nomSociete\":\"COFTECH\",\"tel\":\"05.60.23.05.46\"}]"

Comment: You inspired me to ditch the foreach loop and replace it with this query :  $fournisseurs=FourCats::join('fournisseurs','four_cat.four', '=', 'fournisseurs.id')
                        ->where('four_cat.cat', 'IN' ,$query)
                        ->select('fournisseurs.id','fournisseurs.nomSociete','fournisseurs.id','fournisseurs.tel')
                        ->get();   but it is not returning any rows, i think the problem is in $query   it's  an array Array
(
    [0] => 29
) how can i transform it into this format : ->where('four_cat.cat', 'IN' ,(29,31)).

Comment: Maybe this:->whereIn('four_cat.cat', $query)

Comment: yes i used that after some googling thank you so much for your effort and guidance

Comment: please upvote or check this as answered so I will get some points :-) THX.